# sql sum sales between date

Tags: sql, date, sum, range, ansi-sql

The image explains everything. My aim is to the last table using sql.

I will explain the logic with an example.

Table 1 shows the expected sales. For instance, article 22 should be sold only between 1 janv and 4 jan. To make it simple we assume that shops are open every day.

Table 2 shows the daily sales for each article. For instance article was sold 1 janv 2 janv 3 janv 4 janv. However, for article 22 4 janv is not in the range [1 janv to 3 janv]. Thus to get the sum of sales of article 22, we should omit the 4 jan. Therefore the calculation for article 22 is 2+4+5=11.

[image]

DataType

Table 1

- artNo: int
- from: date
- planned_to: date

Table 2

- artNo: int
- day: date
- sales: float

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Dont be lazy and explain the logic. We don't have time to decode your code and guess what you need.

Comment: Strange date formats. Column data type?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  I added an explanation.

Comment: @jarlh I have tagged  ANSI SQL

Comment: Column data type? The ANSI SQL date format is not what you have in your tables,.

Comment: anything wrong with Chris answer?

Comment: @jarl data type description added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.artNo
    , t1.[from]
    , t1.planned_to
    , SUM(t2.sales) total
FROM
    table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON
        t1.artNo = t2.artNo
        AND t2.day >= t1.[from]
        AND t2.day <= t1.planned_to
GROUP BY
    t1.artNo
    , t1.[from]
    , t1.planned_to
```

Comment: This is not correct ... last line won't be in the result

Comment: @Valerica why wont?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  
'cause I did the same thing and my result didn't bring the last line ... but in my code the difference was that I put 4 Apr and 7 Apr in the table instead of 04 Apr and 07. With leading zeroes is working

Comment: Then the problem is with the date format. The query should work ok if the fields are dates

Comment: I updated the post, indeed the format should be DATE.

Comment: @Chris thanks a lot for the proposition. I was not thinking about doing the range date selection inside the join...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.artNO
    ,t1.
    ,t1.planned_to
    ,SUM(sales) as Total
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.artNo = t2.artNo
GROUP BY t1.artNO
    ,t1.
    ,t1.planned_to
```

Comment: This doesnt handle the date ranges in anyway.